# Not showing the number of items when a folder is empty

Tags: powershell-2.0

I'm new to PowerShell, so please be patient.  I'm writing my first script.
I have a variable to count the number of files before and after deleting.  It shows before deleting, but after deleting it doesn’t show “0”.  Does it only count if the number of items are >=1?

Here's my script

```
# Stops the spooler service
```

## Clears the contents of the printer spool folder

## Restarts the spooler service

## sets the directory for print spool

```
$PrintSpoolLocation = "C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS\*"
```

## shows the contents of the PrintSpoolLocation folder

```
$ShowFiles = Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS\ | Select-Object Name, LastWriteTime
```

## counts the number of items before deleting

```
$CountBefore = (Get-ChildItem c:\windows\system32\spool\PRINTERS).Count
```

Stop-Service -name spooler -force

Remove-Item $PrintSpoolLocation -force

$ShowFiles

## counts the number of items after deleting

```
$CountAfter = (Get-ChildItem c:\windows\system32\spool\PRINTERS).Count
```

Write-Host "`n`nBefore deleting $CountBefore, and after deleting $CountAfter items!"

Restart-Service -name spooler -force

Set-Executionpolicy Unrestricted

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9Irr.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of PowerShell have dubious null handling.  Try checking to see if the object is null manually.

```
$SpoolerItems = Get-ChildItem c:\windows\system32\spool\PRINTERS
if ($SpoolerItems)
{
  $CountAfter = $SpoolerItems.Count
}
else
{
  $CountAfter = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I"ll try it and let you know.